# How to increase character length for title in views-slideshow module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, slideshow

Im maintaining this Drupal Site which is using Slideshow Views for displaying the featured posts. Its using ***Slideshow Thumbnailhover SlideShows*** contribution of '***Views Slideshow***' http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow Module for Drupal. However, even after scanning through the code and browsing though all settings, I cant figure out how to increase the max -character length of titles. Its currently set to 50. I want to increase it to 70.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

```
The exported view is as follows:

$view = new view;
$view->name = 'SlideShows';
$view->description = 'Various views that display content in slideshows';
$view->tag = '';
$view->view_php = '';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->is_cacheable = FALSE;
$view->api_version = 2;
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Defaults', 'default');
$handler->override_option('fields', array(
  'field_upload_image_fid' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
      'html' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 1,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'label_type' => 'none',
    'format' => 'Slideshow_656x400_default',
    'multiple' => array(
      'group' => 0,
      'multiple_number' => '',
      'multiple_from' => '',
      'multiple_reversed' => 0,
    ),
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'field_upload_image_fid',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_upload_image',
    'field' => 'field_upload_image_fid',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'field_upload_image_data' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 1,
      'max_length' => '80',
      'word_boundary' => 0,
      'ellipsis' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'data_key' => 'description',
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'field_upload_image_data',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_upload_image',
    'field' => 'field_upload_image_data',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('sorts', array(
  'created' => array(
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'granularity' => 'second',
    'id' => 'created',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'created',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('arguments', array(
  'nid' => array(
    'default_action' => 'default',
    'style_plugin' => 'default_summary',
    'style_options' => array(),
    'wildcard' => 'all',
    'wildcard_substitution' => 'All',
    'title' => '',
    'breadcrumb' => '',
    'default_argument_type' => 'node',
    'default_argument' => '',
    'validate_type' => 'node',
    'validate_fail' => 'not found',
    'break_phrase' => 0,
    'not' => 0,
    'id' => 'nid',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'nid',
    'validate_user_argument_type' => 'uid',
    'validate_user_roles' => array(
      '2' => 0,
    ),
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'default_options_div_prefix' => '',
    'default_argument_user' => 0,
    'default_argument_fixed' => '',
    'default_argument_php' => '',
    'validate_argument_node_type' => array(
      'blogs' => 0,
      'industry_focus' => 0,
      'market_sectors' => 0,
      'page' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_node_access' => 0,
    'validate_argument_nid_type' => 'nid',
    'validate_argument_vocabulary' => array(
      '1' => 0,
      '6' => 0,
      '3' => 0,
      '2' => 0,
      '5' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_type' => 'tid',
    'validate_argument_transform' => 0,
    'validate_user_restrict_roles' => 0,
    'validate_argument_php' => '',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('filters', array(
  'status' => array(
    'operator' => '=',
    'value' => '1',
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'status',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'status',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'type' => array(
    'operator' => 'in',
    'value' => array(
      'association' => 'association',
      'blogs' => 'blogs',
      'cars' => 'cars',
      'company_reports' => 'company_reports',
      'events' => 'events',
      'howto' => 'howto',
      'news' => 'news',
      'press_releases' => 'press_releases',
      'testimonial' => 'testimonial',
      'travel' => 'travel',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'type',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'type',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'delta' => array(
    'operator' => 'not empty',
    'value' => array(
      'value' => '',
      'min' => '',
      'max' => '',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'delta',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_upload_image',
    'field' => 'delta',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('access', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
$handler->override_option('cache', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
$handler->override_option('header_format', '3');
$handler->override_option('header_empty', 0);
$handler->override_option('footer_format', '2');
$handler->override_option('footer_empty', 0);
$handler->override_option('use_ajax', TRUE);
$handler->override_option('distinct', 1);
$handler->override_option('style_plugin', 'slideshow');
$handler->override_option('style_options', array(
  'type' => 'ul',
  'mode' => 'views_slideshow_thumbnailhover',
  'views_slideshow_singleframe-prefix' => '',
  'views_slideshow_singleframe' => array(
    'timeout' => '6000',
    'delay' => '0',
    'speed' => '700',
    'start_paused' => 0,
    'fixed_height' => '1',
    'random' => '0',
    'pause' => '1',
    'pause_on_click' => '0',
    'remember_slide' => 0,
    'remember_slide_days' => '1',
    'controls' => '0',
    'pager' => '2',
    'pager_type' => 'Numbered',
    'pager_hover' => '2',
    'pager_click_to_page' => 0,
    'image_count' => '0',
    'effect' => 'fade',
    'sync' => '1',
    'nowrap' => '0',
    'advanced' => '',
    'ie' => array(
      'cleartype' => 'true',
      'cleartypenobg' => 'false',
    ),
  ),
  'views_slideshow_thumbnailhover-prefix' => '',
  'views_slideshow_thumbnailhover' => array(
    'hover_breakout' => 'title',
    'teasers_last' => 1,
    'timeout' => '5000',
    'delay' => '0',
    'speed' => '300',
    'start_paused' => 0,
    'fixed_height' => '1',
    'random' => '0',
    'pause' => '1',
    'pause_on_click' => '0',
    'remember_slide' => 0,
    'remember_slide_days' => '1',
    'pager_event' => 'mouseover',
    'controls' => '0',
    'image_count' => '0',
    'effect' => 'fade',
    'sync' => '1',
    'nowrap' => '1',
    'advanced' => '',
    'ie' => array(
      'cleartype' => 'true',
      'cleartypenobg' => 'false',
    ),
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('row_plugin', 'node');
$handler->override_option('row_options', array(
  'relationship' => 'none',
  'build_mode' => 'full',
  'links' => 0,
  'comments' => 0,
));
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'BlockImageSlideshow', 'block_1');
$handler->override_option('use_ajax', FALSE);
$handler->override_option('use_pager', '0');
$handler->override_option('distinct', 0);
$handler->override_option('style_options', array(
  'type' => 'ul',
  'mode' => 'views_slideshow_singleframe',
  'views_slideshow_singleframe-prefix' => '',
  'views_slideshow_singleframe' => array(
    'timeout' => '5000',
    'delay' => '0',
    'speed' => '700',
    'start_paused' => 0,
    'fixed_height' => '1',
    'random' => '0',
    'pause' => '1',
    'pause_on_click' => '0',
    'remember_slide' => 0,
    'remember_slide_days' => '1',
    'controls' => '0',
    'pager' => '2',
    'pager_type' => 'Numbered',
    'pager_hover' => '2',
    'pager_click_to_page' => 0,
    'image_count' => '0',
    'effect' => 'none',
    'sync' => '1',
    'nowrap' => '0',
    'advanced' => '',
    'ie' => array(
      'cleartype' => 'false',
      'cleartypenobg' => 'false',
    ),
  ),
  'views_slideshow_thumbnailhover-prefix' => '',
  'views_slideshow_thumbnailhover' => array(
    'main_fields' => array(
      'field_upload_image_fid' => 0,
      'field_upload_image_data' => 0,
    ),
    'breakout_fields' => array(
      'field_upload_image_fid' => 0,
      'field_upload_image_data' => 0,
    ),
    'teasers_last' => 1,
    'timeout' => '5000',
    'delay' => '0',
    'speed' => '300',
    'start_paused' => 0,
    'fixed_height' => '1',
    'random' => '0',
    'pause' => '1',
    'pause_on_click' => '0',
    'remember_slide' => 0,
    'remember_slide_days' => '1',
    'pager_event' => 'mouseover',
    'controls' => '0',
    'image_count' => '0',
    'effect' => 'fade',
    'sync' => '1',
    'nowrap' => '1',
    'advanced' => '',
    'ie' => array(
      'cleartype' => 'true',
      'cleartypenobg' => 'false',
    ),
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('row_plugin', 'fields');
$handler->override_option('row_options', array());
$handler->override_option('block_description', 'Block: REFID Image Slideshow');
$handler->override_option('block_caching', -1);
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'BlockTopStories', 'block_2');
$handler->override_option('fields', array(
  'field_upload_image_fid' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
      'html' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'label_type' => 'none',
    'format' => 'Thumb_50x50_linked',
    'multiple' => array(
      'group' => 1,
      'multiple_number' => '1',
      'multiple_from' => '',
      'multiple_reversed' => 0,
    ),
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'field_upload_image_fid',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_upload_image',
    'field' => 'field_upload_image_fid',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'title' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 1,
      'max_length' => '55',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
      'html' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 1,
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'title',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'title',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('arguments', array(
  'gid' => array(
    'default_action' => 'default',
    'style_plugin' => 'default_summary',
    'style_options' => array(),
    'wildcard' => 'all',
    'wildcard_substitution' => 'All',
    'title' => '',
    'breadcrumb' => '',
    'default_argument_type' => 'current_domain',
    'default_argument' => '',
    'validate_type' => 'none',
    'validate_fail' => 'not found',
    'id' => 'gid',
    'table' => 'domain_access',
    'field' => 'gid',
    'validate_user_argument_type' => 'uid',
    'validate_user_roles' => array(
      '2' => 0,
    ),
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'default_options_div_prefix' => '',
    'default_argument_user' => 0,
    'default_argument_fixed' => '',
    'default_argument_php' => '',
    'validate_argument_node_type' => array(
      'associations' => 0,
      'blogs' => 0,
      'company_profile' => 0,
      'company_reports' => 0,
      'events' => 0,
      'industry_focus' => 0,
      'market_sectors' => 0,
      'page' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_node_access' => 0,
    'validate_argument_nid_type' => 'nid',
    'validate_argument_vocabulary' => array(
      '1' => 0,
      '6' => 0,
      '7' => 0,
      '3' => 0,
      '2' => 0,
      '5' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_type' => 'tid',
    'validate_argument_transform' => 0,
    'validate_user_restrict_roles' => 0,
    'validate_argument_php' => '',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('filters', array(
  'status' => array(
    'operator' => '=',
    'value' => '1',
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'status',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'status',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'type' => array(
    'operator' => 'in',
    'value' => array(
      'news' => 'news',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'type',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'type',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'delta' => array(
    'operator' => 'not empty',
    'value' => array(
      'value' => '',
      'min' => '',
      'max' => '',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'delta',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_upload_image',
    'field' => 'delta',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'field_news_feature_value_many_to_one' => array(
    'operator' => 'or',
    'value' => array(
      '0' => '0',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'field_news_feature_value_many_to_one',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_news_feature',
    'field' => 'field_news_feature_value_many_to_one',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'reduce_duplicates' => 0,
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('style_plugin', 'viewscarousel');
$handler->override_option('style_options', array(
  'grouping' => '',
  'skin' => 'custom',
  'skin_path' => 'sites/all/themes/exdigital/carousel/style.css',
  'vertical' => 0,
  'start' => '',
  'offset' => '',
  'scroll' => '1',
  'visible' => 0,
  'animation' => 'fast',
  'easing' => '',
  'auto' => '0',
  'wrap' => 'both',
));
$handler->override_option('row_plugin', 'fields');
$handler->override_option('row_options', array());
$handler->override_option('block_description', 'Block: TopStories Slide');
$handler->override_option('block_caching', -1);
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'BlockFrontNews', 'block_3');
$handler->override_option('fields', array(
  'field_upload_image_fid' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
      'html' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'label_type' => 'none',
    'format' => 'Slide_Front_430_linked',
    'multiple' => array(
      'group' => 0,
      'multiple_number' => '',
      'multiple_from' => '',
      'multiple_reversed' => 0,
    ),
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'field_upload_image_fid',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_upload_image',
    'field' => 'field_upload_image_fid',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'title' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 1,
      'max_length' => '55',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
      'html' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 1,
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'title',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'title',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'field_headline_caption_value' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 1,
      'max_length' => '150',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'label_type' => 'none',
    'format' => 'default',
    'multiple' => array(
      'group' => TRUE,
      'multiple_number' => '',
      'multiple_from' => '',
      'multiple_reversed' => FALSE,
    ),
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'field_headline_caption_value',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_headline_caption',
    'field' => 'field_headline_caption_value',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('arguments', array(
  'gid' => array(
    'default_action' => 'default',
    'style_plugin' => 'default_summary',
    'style_options' => array(),
    'wildcard' => 'all',
    'wildcard_substitution' => 'All',
    'title' => '',
    'breadcrumb' => '',
    'default_argument_type' => 'current_domain',
    'default_argument' => '',
    'validate_type' => 'none',
    'validate_fail' => 'not found',
    'id' => 'gid',
    'table' => 'domain_access',
    'field' => 'gid',
    'validate_user_argument_type' => 'uid',
    'validate_user_roles' => array(
      '2' => 0,
    ),
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'default_options_div_prefix' => '',
    'default_argument_user' => 0,
    'default_argument_fixed' => '',
    'default_argument_php' => '',
    'validate_argument_node_type' => array(
      'association' => 0,
      'blogs' => 0,
      'company_reports' => 0,
      'events' => 0,
      'industry_focus' => 0,
      'market_sectors' => 0,
      'news' => 0,
      'page' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_node_access' => 0,
    'validate_argument_nid_type' => 'nid',
    'validate_argument_vocabulary' => array(
      '1' => 0,
      '6' => 0,
      '7' => 0,
      '3' => 0,
      '2' => 0,
      '5' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_type' => 'tid',
    'validate_argument_transform' => 0,
    'validate_user_restrict_roles' => 0,
    'validate_argument_php' => '',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('filters', array(
  'status' => array(
    'operator' => '=',
    'value' => '1',
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'status',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'status',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'type' => array(
    'operator' => 'in',
    'value' => array(
      'news' => 'news',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'type',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'type',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'field_news_feature_value_many_to_one' => array(
    'operator' => 'or',
    'value' => array(
      '2' => '2',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'field_news_feature_value_many_to_one',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_news_feature',
    'field' => 'field_news_feature_value_many_to_one',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'reduce_duplicates' => 0,
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('title', 'News');
$handler->override_option('use_ajax', FALSE);
$handler->override_option('items_per_page', 5);
$handler->override_option('block_description', 'BlockFrontNews');
$handler->override_option('block_caching', -1);
```

Comment: Found the solution.The view was using row style plugin which themed it in the node-[node-type].tpl file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.The view was using row style plugin which themed it in the node-[node-type].tpl file.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to trim the field length on the view field settings, but heard to tell what is going on with out more information such as what templates are overridden, css, etc.

Can you export the view and post it?